# In Azure SQL what happens if allocated space is equal to maximum space - is performance impacted

Tags: azure-sql-database, size

Need some help in understanding what exactly is Allocated Space and Maximum Space.

When it says Maximum allocated space is 500 DB does this include both data and log?

If Allocated space reaches Maximum space is it entire space is allocated to Data only?

My DB stats-

- **Used Space** :  406 GB
- **Allocated** : 500 GB
- **Maximum** : 500 GB

Basically, i am having performance issues with my DB recently, with huge Log IO impacting the DTU.

Any help on these lines would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The maximum file size does not include the log size and XTP files. They are also excluded for the purposes of determining database size. By the way, they are automatically managed by SQL Azure's infrastructure.

Depending on the tier the database gets a specific amount of log space.  With vCore you are allotted a fix amount of space for your logs when you set the storage size. For example, if you specify 1TB of storage, you get 300GB allocated for log.

You can verify the size of the log and the percentage in use with the following statement:

```
DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE)
```

Use the following DMVs to monitor transactions if you are getting errors related to the log size: Following DMVs can be used to monitor transactions: sys.dm_tran_active_transactions, sys.dm_tran_database_transactions, sys.dm_tran_locks, sys.dm_tran_session_transactions. There are some limitations for example: the log limit per transaction is 2 GB and sessions consuming greater than one million locks are terminated.

Uncommitted transactions can block the truncation of log files. To prevent this, the distance from the oldest active transaction log sequence number (LSN) to the tail of the log (current LSN) cannot exceed 20% of the size of the log file. When violated, the offending transaction is terminated and rolled back so that the log can be truncated.

To avoid getting throttled for row operations, reduce the size of data in your transaction, for example by reducing the number of rows or splitting the operation into multiple transactions. To avoid getting throttled for table/index operations that require a single transaction, ensure that the following formula is adhered to:

> number of rows affected in table * (avg size of field being updated in
>   bytes + 80) < 2 GB